# If logic in SQL or Access queries

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Greetings, fellow SO people.

I am working on a project that has me working with an Access database.  Here's the setup:

I have three tables:

```
Tab1 with employee names, ID#s, Manager names and Manager ID#s.
Tab2 with chat info, employee ID#s and employee names.
Tab3 with Manager ID#s, Manager names and team names.
```

I currently have a query that selects the following:

```
tab2.[employee name], tab2.[employee id], tab3.[chat info], tab1.[manager id], tab1.[manager id], tab3.[team name]
where
tab2.[employee id] = tab1.[employee id] and tab2.[manager id] = tab3.[manager id];
```

What I am trying to accomplish is this: I would like to have a way to put "Unknown" in the "Team" field if the IDs don't match up somewhere along the line.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might also want to remove the MySQL tag; the syntax here looks very Access specific.

Comment: Why are the tables named so generically? Why the rampant denormalization? Don't inconsistent IDs mean inconsistent data?

Comment: @user
The tables are named so generically because I didn't know if I could post the real names due to company policy.

Comment: @user
Also, not sure what de-normalization is (it's been a few years since I took SQL) and what IDs are inconsistent?

Comment: __names__: Good point about company policy, but maybe make up some different, but meaningful, table names to help people understand your schema more easily. __denormalization__: Loosely speaking, this means the same field occurs in multiple tables unnecessarily. For example, in *Tab1* you have both manager name and manager ID, whereas (presumably) just the ID would suffice. This can be problematic not only because it takes more space, but because updates need to change several tables to maintain consistency. __inconsistent__: This is in reference to "if the IDs don't match up somewhere".

Comment: (__inconsistent__, continued:) I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the IDs not matching up, but it *might* be a problem--can you clarify your intent? For example, if every employee is *meant* to be assigned to a team, but "the IDs don't match up", rather than expending effort trying to figure out how to return "unknown" for the team field, your time might be better spent validating the data at the point where it enters the database (or is updated). That is, the data in your database should *make sense* (be semantically consistent), rather than relying on hacks in your query code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
select tab2.[employee name], 
       tab2.[employee id], 
       tab3.[chat info], 
       tab1.[manager id], 
       Nz(tab3.[team name], 'Unknown') as [team name]
    from (tab2
        left join tab1
            on tab2.[employee id] = tab1.[employee id])
        left join tab3
            on tab2.[manager id] = tab3.[manager id]
```

Comment: Apparently access doesn't support COALESCE either :-/

Comment: @El Yobo: A quick Google and it looks like Nz is the Access equivalent of COALESCE.

Comment: You will need parenthesis as well.

Comment: Thanks, Joe, but now I get an error: "Syntax error in JOIN operation"

Comment: Add more parentheses in the join expression!

Comment: What do you mean, Ken?  I have the "()" around the tab2 left join line just like Joe shows above.  What am I missing?

Comment: OK, it turns out that I was messing up my variables.  When I straightened that out, Joe's method worked perfectly.  Thanks to all of you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   tab2.[employee name], tab2.[employee id], 
   tab3.[chat info], tab1.[manager id], 
   tab1.[manager id], 
   Nz(tab3.[team name],"Unknown")
FROM (tab2 
LEFT JOIN tab1 
ON tab2.[employee id] = tab1.[employee id]) 
LEFT JOIN tab3 
ON tab2.[manager id] = tab3.[manager id];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Access doesn't support SQL case statements, so my previous answer is incorrect.  I'm leaving it there for anyone looking for the same problem with a SQL compliant database.

Apparently you can use a switch statement to achieve the same result; this example shows [how a switch can be used](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/510436-case-statements-using-sql-ms-access).  Hopefully that's more helpful.

Otherwise, if possible, switch to a real DB :)

Comment: There are lots of SQL dialects. None of them are "real SQL".

Comment: I find that if you're depending on SWITCH() or CHOOSE(), you've likely got a design error, since those are ways of storing data in your SQL statements. That is, if you're depending on those, you should likely put the data in them in a lookup table so you can leverage SQL properly.

Comment: @David: real DB, not real SQL.  There is a standard, and most databases comply to some extend.  Access is certainly one of the least compliant.

Comment: Access or Jet/ACE? Anybody who suggests that Jet/ACE is not a "real DB" is someone whose advice I feel safe in ignoring entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was slow off the mark with the fact that you can't use CASE, and Joe's use of Nz is probably your best bet, but there is another Access-specific alternative, presented here in case it fits your situation better:

```
select tab2.[employee name],
       tab2.[employee id],
       tab3.[chat info],
       tab1.[manager id],
       Iif(IsNull(tab3.[team name]), 'Unknown', tab3.[team name]) as [team name]
    from tab2
        left join tab1
            on tab2.[employee id] = tab1.[employee id]
        left join tab3
            on tab2.[manager id] = tab3.[manager id]
```

In this situation, Iif( *condition, trueAnswer, falseAnswer* ) does the same thing as the Nz, but if your *condition* is something besides an IsNull it can be more flexible.

Comment: You are still short on parenthesis, Access is fussy about them when creating joins.

Comment: @Remou: You're completely correct--I didn't even deal with the issue of parenteses, just copied Joe's code and changed the Nz call to a an Iif call. Parenteses are... what's the phrase? "An exercise for the reader."

Comment: Once again only addressing Nz/Iif: I just found a link that recommnds using Iif instead of Nz: http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html#Nz

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about Access, but in SQL normally you would left join your tables and you can use a CASE statement to add the conditional behaviour your looking for; access may not support this.

The example shown [here](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/15633) is reasonably standard.

Wow, do access queries really look like that?  Hmmm... Then perhaps something like this.

```
tab2.[employee name], tab2.[employee id], tab3.[chat info], tab1.[manager id], tab1.[manager id], case when tab3.[team name] is null then 'Unknown' else tab3.[team name] end as [team name]
where
tab2.[employee id] = tab1.[employee id] and tab2.[manager id] = tab3.[manager id];
```

Comment: If you're not sure about Access, DON'T POST AN ANSWER.

Comment: Easy with your down voting tiger; I'm not sure about access, but the CASE syntax is applicable to any SQL compliant database, so it's worth suggesting it.

Comment: This is an Access question. The tag was there from the beginning. SQL that doesn't run in Access is not an answer worth posting. And I'll spend my reputation votes on downvotes whenever I damned well please. Bad answers get a downvote, as they should. And proposing SQL that can't possibly ever work for the question being asked is as deserving of a downvote as anything else, in my opinion.

Comment: There were no other answers when I posted mine, so I judged that providing an answer which would work in most databases and possibly in Access to be helpful. In addition to the original poster, others searching may also come across this question and the answer will again be appropriate in most cases.  You are, of course, welcome to waste your reputation making as many bad downvotes as you like.

Comment: I'm happy to spend reputation in downvoting bad answers because I'm not here to grub reputation points, but to help other people. Making sure a bad answer is clearly marked as such improves the quality of SO, so it's certainly worth it to me spend those reputation points. Personally, when I find out one of my answers is mistaken, if I can't turn it into something useful by editing it, I'll just delete it.

Comment: I agree with the principle, I just disagree with what's useful and what's bad.

Comment: Well, as someone who only reads and posts on Access topics on SO, I can tell you that drive-by T-SQL answers that can't ever work in Access get really tiresome. Thus, I'll continue downvoting any inapplicable answer.